# BackUp Strategies and Tools for MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup

I would like your opinions and thoughts on best practices/strategies and Tools to Backing Up a WebSite with its DataBase. Here I posted some ideas, but I'm not sure what really works in real world scenario and what is feasible (I have a limited experience with DB).

My Web Site and DB are hosted on an external Server A managed by an hosting company, I can access my DataBase using MS Management Studio and files using FTP. Hosting provider offer disaster recovery for the DB but I also need regular BackUp.

Solutions:

01 -
A software running on Server A automatically backup my DB and Files on regular intervals and send the backups to a different Serve B (using FTP).

02 -
A software running on my local PC that manually or automatically backup my DB and Files and save it on my local computer or to another Server B.

My questions:

- What others solutions could be available? Do I miss smt?
- What are the software designed for this jobs (open source or not)?
- What is your experience?

I rally appreciate your time on this. Please let me know thanks.

Notes: I would need regular Back Up weekly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this is same requirement a few months back. Here is my approach

I wrote an application on my local machine and using Windows Task Scheduler I had it run every day. What the application did was make a connection to the database server where my database was residing. Then the application would issue a `BACKUP` command.  This would save the .bak file to the database server and I would utilize FTP for my application to authenticate and download that file to my local machine.

Then you can have automatic file cleanup handled in that application, but that isn't a core necessity.

Comment: Interesting, could you point me in some direction, maybe some online resources or tutorials? Thanks for answer.